# How to read a downloaded file with Chrome Extension MV3?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am trying to calculate a hash of a downloaded file using a Chrome extension.

I have seen the File System Access API but the user needs to select a file.
https://developer.chrome.com/articles/file-system-access/

On the Download API, it does not seems possible to read the file.
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/downloads/

Is what I am trying to do feasible with a Chrome MV3 extension?